# How does Angular set html file as the error file source

Tags: angular

When an error occurs in any html.component file, angular in some "magic" way throw an error in the console and sets the `ClassComponent.html` as the source of the thrown error.

## P.S this is not a code issue, but something to learn from its logic.

How does that happen and how when clicking on that `ClassComponent.html` it opens in the Sources panel it shows am HTML file and highlights the line that caused that error?

A simple example something like this:

`home.component.html`

```html
<li *ngIf="user.name">{{ user.name }}</li>
```

As the `user` property is not even defined, then it will throw an error in the console that indicates `call to name property of undefined` at `HomeConponent.html:1`, something like that.

I tried to trace it from the `@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js` but at some point the error trace comes from nowhere.

any clues about what happens behind the scenes for that matter?

Answer (score 0):

This is thanks to the Template Parser Angular uses for your compiler to  understand what's written in your .html.

This video explains it very well:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kW9cJsvcsGo

It is a fairly long watch, but I believe your specific question is answered from 6:06 onward, although I suggest you watch the whole thing if you can find the time.

Comment: This is actually a very good talk, but unfortunately it doesn't answer my question, which he skipped the part of how does the browser parse `read` the error as if it was from the template file.

Comment: Well from 8:00 the explanation it does tell you how it can figure out which line from your template file the error is from. If that's doesn't answer it, I might have misunderstood your actual question, sorry :/

Comment: Still yes, not my question, i wanted to know how does they tell the browser its from that "html" file regardless the error itself, as i tried many times but it all ended up with the error is thrown from a `js` file not `html` file